# Name of book where Christ returns as a woman, it starts with a meteor strike in Israel

Tags: story-identification, books, urban-fantasy

Meteor strike in Israel on a secret government facility and a woman survives. Later on she performs miracles and is eventually murdered and ambiguously rises. The story is told from the point of view of a reporter who eventually becomes the chronicler of her story. Follows the New Testament, miracles abound but it eventually comes down to faith. NOT kind to organized Christian sects. It was a great story and I would like to get another copy.

Comment: Roughly when did you read this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is "[The Last Day](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0446605980)" by Glenn Kleiner

> Just in time for the millennium, Glenn Kleier mixes bioengineering and
>   religion, miracles and modern warfare, politics and physics to produce
>   a gripping tale set in the Middle East at the dawn of the 21st
>   century. When a mysterious explosion destroys a top-secret laboratory
>   in the Negev desert on Christmas Day 1999, Jonathan Feldman, a
>   reporter, isn't satisfied with the official explanation. Neither is
>   the Vatican, nor an American fundamentalist preacher, nor the
>   patriarch of the Jehovah's Witnesses, all of whom believe that
>   Armageddon may truly be at hand.
>
> After a New Year's Eve earthquake
>   strikes the temple at the Well of David and a mysterious figure
>   appears in the ruins, strange things begin to happen. Reports of
>   miracles filter in from throughout the region, and the legend of Jeza
>   takes on a life of its own. When the young miracle worker chooses
>   Jonathan to connect her to the world and broadcast her warning of the
>   cataclysm to come, the world's religious leaders are plunged into
>   conflict.
>
> Seeking to discredit her, they spread the secret of her high-tech,
>   bioengineered birth. But their actions backfire; Jeza's influence
>   grows. Holy wars break out in the Middle East and chaos erupts all
>   over the world. As Easter 2000 approaches, the political situation
>   grows even more tense: Will there be another crucifixion, another
>   resurrection? Kleier handles this complicated plot with ease, and fans
>   of futuristic thrillers won't be disappointed.